# Difference in SparkSQL Dataframe columns

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

How do I locate difference between 2 dataframe columns ?
This is causing issues when I join 2 dataframes.

df1_cols = df1.columns
df2_cols = df2.columns
This will return columns for 2 dataframe in 2 list variables.

Thanks

Comment: Your question is vague at best. Please do the following:


1. Share sample dataframes

2. Share your code

3. Share your error

4. Share the desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`df.columns` returns a list here, so you can use any tool in python to compare with another list, i.e. `df2_cols`. e.g. You can use `set` to check the common columns in the two DataFrames

```
df1_cols = df1.columns
df2_cols = df2.columns
set(df1_cols).intersection(set(df2_cols))  # check common columns
set(df1_cols) - set(df2_cols) # check columns in df1 but not in df2
set(df2_cols) - set(df1_cols) # check columns in df2 but not in df1
```